# NASM macro-deal with any addressing mode

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

Write a NASM macro: divide, which has 2 arguments, which specify unsigned integers in any addressing mode. The macro computes the ceiling of its first argument, divided by its second argument, and places the result in register edx. If the second argument is 0 (to be tested at runtime), the result should be 0, and a message "divide by zero" should be printed to stdout.

How can I tell which is which, so we can handle each case?
(;The address modes are: register, memory, and immediate.)

edit:
this is the final code i wrote:
how to  write this code without labels? (position indepen code):

```
%macro divide 2

section .rodata
        LC1: DB "divide by zero ", 10, 0

section .text

  mov eax, %1
  mov ebx, %2
  cmp ebx, 0 ; divide by zero
  jne rest1
  push LC1
  call printf
  add esp,4
  mov edx, 0
  jmp end1

rest1:
  mov edx, 0
  div ebx
  add eax, edx
  mov edx , eax ; the result should be in edx

end1:
 %endmacro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to tell which is which. Loading a general-purpose register such as `EAX` is possible with the `MOV` instruction from any location (another register, memory, immediate constant). Take advantage of that.

**EDIT**:

To make it even more clear, this is how you could write a macro like that:

```
%macro mydiv 2
  mov eax, %1
  mov ebx, %2
  mov edx, 0
  div ebx
%endmacro
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
  mydiv 3, 2 ; 2 immediate operands

  mov ebx, 15
  mov ecx, 3
  mydiv ebx, ecx ; 2 register operands

  mydiv [dividend], [divisor] ; 2 memory operands

...

  dividend dd 42
  divisor  dd 6
```

Of course, the way the macro is defined imposes certain restrictions on where the division operands can be located. For instance, operand 2 (divisor) cannot be in `EAX` because `mov ebx, eax` would load `EBX` with operand 1 (dividend) since the preceding instruction `mov eax, %1` would put the dividend into `EAX`.

You can work around that by using the stack:

```
%macro mydiv2 2
  push  ebx
  push  %1
  push  %2
  pop   ebx
  pop   eax
  mov   edx, 0
  div   ebx
  pop   ebx
%endmacro
```

This macro will accept the divisor and dividend from any registers just fine and it won't trash `EBX`. The only (minor) problem with it will be when your operand(s) is/are in memory and addressed relative to `ESP`, e.g.:

```
mydiv2 eax, [esp+8]
```

Those pushes change `ESP` and that has to be accounted for.

**EDIT2**:

There's one caveat with `mydiv2`... It will push immediate constants (such as 123) as 16-bit in 16-bit mode and 32-bit in 32-bit mode but will pop them as 32-bit ones. To make  `mydiv2` work in 16-bit mode you'd need to prefix the immediate constants with `dword`:

```
  mydiv2 dword 3, dword 2 ; 2 immediate operands
```

You can now implement the rest of the needed functionality in the macro.

Comment: but eax can be a value and can be an address. no?

Comment: `EAX` is a register. It can contain different values. Generally speaking, whether those are addresses or not is up to you. Just `MOV register, argument` in the macro. And when you're invoking this macro this argument can be 123, ECX, [EBX*4+EDI-3], whatever you want.

Comment: thank you!  I have another question:  Re-write the above macro to produce only strictly position-independent code, under the assumption that the arguments are valid (i.e. if they refer to memory addresses, these addresses are still valid even if the code is moved).  -->> why there is a problem with the standart code(like you write)?

Comment: My macro will assemble into position-independent code itself. The only thing that can make it position-dependent is memory operands supplied to it as arguments. But that's something you need to take into account. Or supply them in registers and/or as immediates.

Comment: I believe I've answered the original question. Please undo the question change and ask another question about position-independent code.